# Why is there a $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $mr - p < \frac{1}{10}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations, computability, formal-languages

I am reading the following part of the [paper of Denef](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-242-00/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7.pdf) :

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $D(x_1,\dots , x_n)$ be a
relation in $R$. We say that $D (x_1,\dots , x_n)$ is diophantine over $R$ if there exists a polynomial $P(x_1,\dots , x_n,y_1,\dots  ,y_m)$ over $R$ such that for all $x_1,\dots , x_n$ in $R$ : $$D(x_1, \dots , x_n) \leftrightarrow \exists y_1, \dots , y_m \in R : P(x_1, \dots , x_n, y_1, \dots , y_m)=0$$

Let $R'$ be a subring of $R$ and suppose $P$ can be chosen such that its
coefficients lay in $R'$, then we say that $D (x_1,\dots , x_n)$ is diophantine over $R$ with coefficients in $R'$.

**Proposition 1.** 
Let $R$ be an integral domain of characteristic zero. Suppose
there exists a subset $S$ of $R$ which contains $\mathbb{Z}$ and which is diophantine over $R[T]$; then $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$. 
In particular, this is true when $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$.

A relation is diophantine over $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ if and only if it is recursively enumerable.

**Corollary (M. Boffa).** 
Every subset $D$ of $\mathbb{N}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$.

*Proof.* 
Let $r$ be the real number $r = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{10^{n+1}}$, where $a_n = 0$ for $n \in D$ and $a_n = 1$ for $n \notin D$. 
Then we have
$$n \in D \leftrightarrow n \in N \land \exists p, m \in N: \left (m = 10^n \land 0 \leq mr - p < \frac{1}{10}\right )$$ 
But $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$ by Proposition $1$, and every recursively enumerable relation in $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, using elementary algebra, we see that $D$ is diophantine over $R[T]$.

$$$$

I haven't understood the equivalence: $n \in D \leftrightarrow n \in N \land \exists p, m \in N: \left (m = 10^n \land 0 \leq mr - p < \frac{1}{10}\right )$

When $n \in D$ we have that $a_n=0$.

$r=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1}} \geq 0$ since the numeratoe is always $0$ or $1$.

We take $m=10^n$ so $mr=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}$.

Since $a_n=0$ we don't get the term $\frac{1}{10}$ at the sum.

But how do we know that there is a $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $mr - p < \frac{1}{10}$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Could you explain to me the following part of the proof?

"But $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$ by Proposition $1$, and every recursively enumerable relation in $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, using elementary algebra, we see that $D$ is diophantine over $R[T]$."

By Proposition $1$ we have that $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$ when there is a subset $S$ of $R$ which contains $\mathbb{Z}$ and which is diophantine over $R[T]$.

Which is in this case the subset $S$ ?

Comment: If $R$ is a integral domain with characteristic zero it contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. This will be your subset $S$ in $R$.

Comment: @MrSelberg: we don't know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the sum $mr$ in $M+R$ where $M$ is the sum from $i=0$ to $n-1$ (that means, the part of the sum which terms are integers), and $R$ is the tail of the sum (from $i=n$ to infinity.) Define $p=M$. Then $mr-p=R$. You can estimate the sum $R$ taking account that is bounded by $\sum_{i\geq 2}1/10^n$.

Comment: Is it as followed? 

$$mr=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}$$ 
$$p:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}$$ 
$$mr=p+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \\ \Rightarrow mr-p=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{i+1-n}}<\frac{1}{10^{(n+1)+1-n}}=\frac{1}{10^2}<\frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: Not at all. The sum $$\sum_{i\geq n+1}\frac{1}{10^{i+1-n}}$$ have the term $1/10^2$ and more, hence that ineq. is wrong ($>$ is the correct symbol). Moreover, you can evaluate the exact value using geometric series.

Comment: $$mr=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}$$ 
$$p:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}}$$ 
$$mr=p+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \\ \Rightarrow mr-p=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{i+1-n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{k+2}}\leq \frac{1}{10^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{1}{10^2}\frac{1}{9}$$ Is it correct so far? How do we continue to get $<\frac{1}{10}$ ?

Comment: Erase the term $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_i}{10^{k+2}}.$$
Moreover $\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{10}{9}$, then $mr-p\leq 1/90<1/10$.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right!! So it is $$mr=p+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \\ \Rightarrow mr-p=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{i+1-n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{k+2}‌​}= \frac{1}{10^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{1}{10^2}\frac{10}{9}=\frac{1}{9 \cdot 10}<\frac{1}{10}$$ And we also have that $$mr-p=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^{i+1-n}} \geq 0$$ since $a_n=0$ or $a_n=1$ right?

Comment: Could you also explain to me the following part of the proof? $$$$ "But $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$ by Proposition $1$, and every recursively enumerable relation in $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, using elementary algebra, we see that $D$ is diophantine over $R[T]$."

Comment: @MaryStar read my comment above in your question.

Answer (score 1):

We can think of $R$ sitting inside the polynomial ring $R[T]$ as the set of polynomials of degree 0, and because $R$ is an integral domain of characteristic $0$, we can think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subring of $R \subseteq R[T]$. What the first part of the proposition is saying is that, if there is some subset $S$ of $R[T]$ with $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq S \subseteq R$ that is diophantine over $R[T]$, then $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$. In the second part, "$R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$" means that every non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq R$ is invertible, so we can consider $\mathbb{Q}$ to be a subring of $R$ with $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subseteq R$. The second part then says that, in this case, we can always define a subset $S$ of $R$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$ that is diophantine over $R[T]$. To do this, note that for $f, g \in R[T]$, $fg = 1$ implies that $\deg(f)=\deg(g) = 0$, i.e., that $f, g \in R$, so we can define $S$ by
$$
S = \{ f \in R[T] \mathrel{|} f = 0 \lor (\exists g \in R[T]\cdot fg = 1)\}.
$$
Then $S$ is clearly diophantine over $R[T]$, and, given that $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$, we have $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subseteq S \subseteq R$.

Comment: At the beginning you say: "...because $R$ is an integral domain of characteristic $0$, we can think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subring of $R \subseteq R[T]$." Why does this hold?

Comment: We can identify $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $i \times 1$ in $R$.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me? I haven't understood it...

Comment: $R$ has a unit element $1$ and hence it has the elements $-1$, $1+1$, $-1 + -1$ etc. We can identify these elements with the corresponding elements of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: And is this a consequence of the fact that $R$ is an integral domain of characteristic $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, To say a ring has characteristic $0$ means precisely that this mapping is one-to-one.

Comment: So, when a ring $R$ has characteristic zero there is a one-to-one mapping from $R$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, right? At which point do we need the fact that $R$ is an intergral domain?