# Why does this equivalence stand?

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, computability, equivalence-relations, formal-languages

I am reading the proof of the following theorem:

> **THEOREM A.**
>
> Let $R$ be an integral domain of characteristic zero; then the
>   diophantine problem for $R[T]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}T]$ is
>   unsolvable.
>
> ($R[T]$ denotes the ring of polynomials over $R$, in one variable
>   $T$.)

at a [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-242-00/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7.pdf).

We write $V \sim W$ to denote that the polynomials $V$ and $W$ in $R[T]$ take the same value at $T=1$.

$$Imt(Y) \leftrightarrow Y \in R[T]\land \exists X\in R[T]: X^2-(T^2-1)Y^2=1$$

**Lemma 2.3.**

We have:

(i) The relation $Imt(Y)$ is diophantine over $R[T]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$.

(ii) If $Y$ satisfies $Imt(Y)$, then there exists an integer $m$ such that $Y \sim m$.

(iii) For every integer $m$ there exists a polynomial $Y$ satisfying $Imt(Y)$ and $Y \sim m$.

Could you take a look at the proof:

[image] and explain to me the following?

$$\exists z_1, \dots , z_n\in \mathbb{Z}: P(z_1, \dots , z_n)=0 \leftrightarrow \exists Z_1, \dots , Z_n\in R[T]: (Imt(Z_1) \land \dots \land Imt(Z_n) \land P(Z_1, \dots , Z_n) \sim 0)$$

Why does this equivalence stand?

Comment: Don't you need to add in Lemma 2.3 into your question so that we don't have to read the paper to find it?

Comment: I added Lemma $2.3$ in my question above... @user21820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I think the formula in the paper was typeset misleadingly and should have read:
$\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\def\eq{\Leftrightarrow}$

> $\exists z_1,\cdots,z_n \in \zz\ ( P(z_1,\cdots,z_n) = 0 )$
>
> $\ \eq \exists Z_1,\cdots,Z_n \in R[T]\ ( Imt(Z_1) \land \cdots \land Imt(Z_n) \land P(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) \sim 0 )$

For the forward implication, for each $k \in [1..n]$ let $Z_k \in R[T]$ such that $Imt(Z_k)$ and $Z_k \sim z_k$ by Lemma 2.3(iii), and then $P(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) \sim P(z_1,\cdots,z_n) = 0$.

For the backward implication, let $z_k \in \zz$ such that $Z_k \sim z_k$ by Lemma 2.3(ii), and then $P(z_1,\cdots,z_n) \sim P(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) \sim 0$. But $P(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ is a constant in $R[T]$ and hence $P(z_1,\cdots,z_n) = 0$.

Comment: At the forward implication I haven't really understood how we concluded that $P(Z_1, \dots , Z_n) \sim P(z_1, \dots , z_n)$. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @MaryStar: $\sim$ is an equivalence relation that only cares about the value of a polynomial in $R[T]$ when $T$ is substituted by $1$. Note that for an expression in $R[T]$ replacing any subexpression with a $\sim$-equivalent expression results in a $\sim$-related expression. So you can replace $Z_k$ for each $k \in [1..n]$ one by one with the corresponding $z_k$ and the result is $\sim$-related to the original.

Comment: I see... Thanks for the explanation!! I have also an other question... You say that $P(z_1, \dots , z_n)$ is a constant in $R[T]$. Does this hold because $z_1, \dots , z_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: Yes a constant expression is one without any indeterminates. When $P$ is said to be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$, it naturally means that once all the indeterminates in the expression for $P$ is substituted by integers, the result is just an integer expression.

Comment: I got it... Thank you very much!! :-) $$$$ Could you maybe take also a look at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400948/why-is-there-a-p-in-mathbbn-such-that-mr-p-frac110/1400984?noredirect=1#comment2853747_1400984 at the edit part?