# Why does this imply that $x \in S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading the proof of the following proposition at a [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1978-242-00/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7/S0002-9947-1978-0491583-7.pdf) but I got stuck at some points...

**Proposition 1.**

Let $R$ be an integral domain of characteristic zero. Suppose there exists a subset $S$ of $R$ which contains $\mathbb{Z}$ and which is diophantine over $R[T]$; then $\mathbb{Z}$ is diophantine over $R[T]$.
In particular, this is true when $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$.

*Proof.*

If $S$ satisfies the conditions of the proposition, then
$$z \in \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow \exists Z \in R[T]: (Imt(Z) \land Z \sim z \ \land \in S)$$

Moreover, if $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$, then we define $S$ by:
$$x \in S \leftrightarrow x \in R[T] \land (x = 0 \lor \exists y \in R[T]:xy = 1)$$

$$$$

I haven't really understood the implication $x \in S \leftrightarrow x \in R[T] \land (x = 0 \lor \exists y \in R[T]:xy = 1)$.

Doesn't the right-hand side of the implication mean that $x \in R[T]$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

But why does this imply that $x \in S$ ?

$\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in $R$ but since $S$ is a subset of $R$ it doesn't mean that $\mathbb{Q}$ is also contained in $S$, right?

Also at the implication $z \in \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow \exists Z \in R[T]: (Imt(Z) \land Z \sim z \ \land \in S)$ what is in $S$ ? Should it maybe be $z \in \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow \exists Z \in R[T]: (Imt(Z) \land Z \sim z \ \land z \in S)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first set of questions, $S$ is *being defined* as the set $\{x\in R[T]: x=0 \vee \exists y\in R[T](xy=1)\}$. Their Proposition 1 might be more clearly rephrased as:

> . . .In particular, if $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$, then there is a set $S$ which is Diophantine over $R[T]$ which contains $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence $\mathbb{Z}$; so if $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{Z}$ is Diophantine over $R[T]$.

The set $S$ is just the set of invertible elements (and zero) of $R[T]$. We're looking at this specific $S$ for the following reason: $R[T]$ might have lots of invertible elements, but certainly every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is invertible, so the specific set $S$ defined above is *at least* $\mathbb{Q}$. Since this $S$ is Diophantine (pretty much immediately by definition), it follows by the first half of Proposition 1 that $\mathbb{Z}$ is Diophantine over $R[T]$. So the whole role of this $S$ is to show how the second sentence of Proposition 1 follows from the first sentence of Proposition 1.

As to your final question, yes, that's a typo - it should end " . . . $z\in S$." Here $S$ is **any set Diophantine over $R[T]$ which contains $\mathbb{Z}$.** In particular, no relation to the previous $S$, which was specifically the set of invertible (or zero) elements of $R[T]$.

Comment: I understand... Thanks for the explanation!! :-) $$$$ Could you maybe take also a look at my other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400948/why-is-there-a-p-in-mathbbn-such-that-mr-p-frac110 at the edit part?